# Set the "from" header in the email to be in the format "Full Name" <email@address.com>

Tags: 7, emails

How can I change the *from* header in the email sent from Drupal to be in the format `"Fullname" <email@address.com>`?

I managed to do it on a Drupal 6 site at one point in the past, but I no longer have access to that site, and I don't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`hook_mail_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) to change the "from" email address of any email sent out from your site. The email address used needs to conform to the RFC standard, which it does is your question's title. But user names can be tricky and might contain illegal characters. There's a comment on the D6 docs that provides a code sample for [properly formatting the email address](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6#comment-4899). Your code would look something like...

```
function yourmodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $message['from'] = $message['headers']['From'] = '"Full Name" <email@address.com>';
}
```

Also, keep in mind that just setting the "from" address may not have the desired results in all email clients (see the [discussion on the Drupal issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/656472)). You might also need to set "sender", "errors-to" and "reply-to" based on your requirements. Those values are in the "header" of the `$message` variable from the code sample above.

Comment: Thanks. For those who arrive at this answer in the future, definitely pay attention to the final paragraph. For example, just setting the $message['from'] did NOT work for me. I had to set the $message['headers']['From'] value.

Comment: Thanks @maxedison. You are right. I'm editting the answer and hope the modification will be accepted.

Comment: setting $message['from'] worked fine for me (5 years later), but watch that you do use the double quotes around from name

Answer (score 11):

This is the method from Drupal 6 to add the the site name to the email.  Substitute  variable_get('site_name, Drupal') with The Site Full Name you want.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_mail_alter().
* Here we allow the site name to be used as the senders name for outgoing email.
* see http://drupal.org/node/209672
*/
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message){
  $default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));

  if($message['from'] == $default_from){
    $message['from'] = '"'. variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal') .'" <'. $default_from .'>';
    $message['headers']['From'] = $message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $message['headers']['Errors-To'] = $message['headers']['Reply-To'] = $message['from'];
  }
}
```

the function for hook_mail_alter() has not change in Drupal 7, so this should work.

Comment: This is worked for me for `Gmail & outlook`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the settings you have to change, this is still an issue in D7. If in doubt, use the following code in your hook_mail_alter :

```
$message['from'] = $from;
$message['headers']['From'] = $from;
$message['headers']['Sender'] = $from;
$message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $from;
```