# Changing the sender of email

Tags: 7, emails

I am using the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module, together with the [PHPMailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/phpmailer) module to send emails. It works perfectly, but only from the email in admin/config/system/site-information. How could I use [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x) or similar hook in order to send from different accounts of the site depending on the situation?

Do I need to install another module, or can it be achieved by using a hook? `hook_mail_alter()` just have "from" but that is a dummy email address which can be even simulated.

Answer (score 2):

After many unsuccesful tests, I have finally found the solution through
[Set the "from" header in the email to be in the format "Full Name" <email@address.com>](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7311/set-drupal-7-from-email-address-to-be-in-the-format-full-name-emailaddress).

In your module, you must use the following code, which can be customized via the ID of the email or other parameters which are contained in the variable $message (which is passed by reference, so can be modified by the hook):

```
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message){

    $from = "user-account@domain.name" ;

    $message['from'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['From'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['Sender'] = $from;
    $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $from;

} // function
```

Comment: u are a genius :)

Answer (score 2):

I used the code from @Cesar above but ran into some trouble. I wanted to specify the name of the sender as well but ran into encoding issues.

This was what I used in the end:

```
function custom_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  $name = variable_get('site_name', 'My awsöme site');
  $mail = variable_get('site_mail', 'contact@myawsomesite.se');
  $message['from'] = mb_encode_mimeheader($name, 'UTF-8', 'Q') . ' <' . $mail . '>';
  $message['headers']['From'] = $message['headers']['Sender'] = $message['from'];
}
```

Setting the `Return-path` header caused the e-mail to be sent to the sender address (contact@myawsomesite.se) as well as the intended recipient.

Comment: For people working on D8, variable_get() become \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail'); and \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name'); in this context.

Answer (score 0):

if that could help someone , a snippet on D8 to send e-mails.
The reply from Cesar with the headers also sorted me out

```
    //logic if i send or not and to who then
    if ($send) {
        $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
        $module = "mymodule";
        $key = 'state_changed_action';
        $to = $send_to;

        $langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();

        $result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);

        if ($result['result'] !== TRUE) {
          drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending notifications.'), 'error');
        }
        else {
          drupal_set_message(t("A notification has been sent to $to"));
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_mail().
     */
    function amu_dud_rules_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
      $options = [
        'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
      ];
      switch ($key) {
        case 'state_changed_action':
          //$message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
          $from='mysite-noreply@mydomain';

          $message['from'] = $from;
          $message['headers']['From'] = $from;
          $message['headers']['Sender'] = $from;
          $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $from;
          $message['subject'] = t('@title', ['@title' => $params['node_title']], $options);
          $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
          break;
      }
    }
```